# How to increase the distance between characters and between lines?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, character, textfield

I need to increase using AS3 the distance between characters in a TextField object, and between lines, I mean, new lines. Is there a way to do this by code?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the **leading** property of the [TextFormat](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextFormat.html#leading) class and maybe also for the **letterSpacing** property.

A possible complication is that when applied by code the TextFormat needs to be re-applied after changing a text field's content.

Addition: To double the space of an actual space (" ") just replace it with two spaces...

```
function strReplace(str:String, search:String, replace:String):String {
  return str.split(search).join(replace);
}
yourText=strReplace(yourText," ","  ");
```

When doing that make sure that the TextField's [condenseWhite](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#condenseWhite) property is set to false.

Comment: Thank you!, it's exactly what I was looking for. Btw, do you know of any way to increase (double actually) the width of the space?, so, instead of having: "this is my house" to have: "this  is  my  house"?. It would like using a letterSpacing but only applicable to the space.